# React Hook: method renders JSX called infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, class, react-hooks

Here you can see a simplified version of my issue:

```js
class Test extends Component {
  state = { text: 'Hello World' };
  rendersomeJSX = () => <Text>{this.props.someValueThatChangesOverTime}</Text>;

  render() {
    return <View>{this.rendersomeJSX()}</View>;
  }
}
```

I am trying to implement the same behaviour using React Hook:

```js
function useTest(props) {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello World');
  function rendersomeJSX() {
    return <Text>{props.someValueThatChangesOverTime}</Text>;
  }
  return <View>{rendersomeJSX()}</View>;
}
```

However, I noticed that my `rendersomeJSX` function is called infinitely, when I am using the second implementation.

What is the correct way of having a function that builds some section of UI and returns it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
import React, { useState, useMemo } from 'react';

function useTest() {
  const [text, setText] = useState('Hello World');
  const someJSX = useMemo(() {
    return <Text>{text}</Text>;
  }, [text]);
  return <View>{someJSX}</View>;
}
```

Comment: Awesome. But do I really need to use useMemo? Because the usage of useMemo is something else.

Comment: @Kasra you can create separate component with text prop